# Returns all rows with Minimum Value in Php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table that consist of records and i want to retrieve rows with minimum price. I try the code below, and i am only able to retrieve only one rows. i need to return all rows with minimum price for the same partno.

```
<tr>
   <th>S/N</th>
   <th>Part Number</th>
   <th>Description  </th>
   <th nowrap="nowrap">Recommended Price</th>
  <th nowrap="nowrap">Recommended Supplier</th>
 </tr>
<?php
$get = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT  MIN(price)As price,partno,supplier,description FROM tab_stockqty2 "); 
$c=0;
while($rw = mysqli_fetch_array($get)){
$c++;?>
<tr>
     <td nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $c;?></td>
     <td nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $rw['partno'];?></td>
     <td nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $rw['description'];?></td>
     <td><?php echo number_format($rw['price'],2);?></td>            
     <td><?php echo $rw['supplier'];?></td>            

      </tr>
<?php };?>
```

See Database Record: [image]

It show return two rows, but it is only retuning only one row for the first set of partno-2070081

Comment: It is normal that it will return just one , cause your query is asking just for the only row that has the min price in the table

Comment: `MIN` aggregate function allows us to select the lowest (minimum) value for a certain column. and It will return only 1 row

Comment: @OmisBrown: How then can i return all rows that have minium price for a distinct partno in the tables?

Comment: use order by price group by partno

Comment: @Narayan: how do i return all rows with minimum price for a distinct partno?

Comment: @Dave check the answer given by me

Comment: Well what do you mean by minimum price?. Is it the lowest price or a certain price limit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve all records with minimal price, per partno, the query should be something like this:

```
SELECT s.price,s.partno,s.supplier,s.description FROM tab_stockqty2 s
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(price) as m, partno FROM tab_stockqty2 GROUP BY 2
) m on s.price = m.m and s.partno = m.partno
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e089/1

Comment: this code retuen only one row, this time it returns the one with the second partno.

Comment: @Dave, check your data. I have added an example to show how it works.

Comment: thanks.  I have added more data, so that you can see that it is not returning all rows . Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/144c96/1

Comment: Hmm, it returns both records with price 1. Are you expecting anything else?

Comment: yes, it should also return the rows with minimum price for p2 item

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer and the example. I'd recommend to review the question, since there is a lot of confusion. May be just prepare a representative dataset in sqlfiddle and expected result.

Comment: Tha nks, Alex. it works.!!!, you only missed  the as after the first ...from tab_stockqty2... Thanks a million. Could you please explain the code to me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145208/discussion-between-dave-and-alex-blex).

Answer (score 1):

try this ==>

```
SELECT  MIN(price)As price,partno,supplier,description FROM tab_stockqty2 group by partno
```

Comment: this returns all rows, but the suuplier, it picks is not for that price?

Comment: @Dave can you please elaborate more. exactly what you want

Comment: This is what i  want- Look at the minimum price for the same partno , and return that row. meaning- it will return the row containing partno, price, supplier, description. This will be done for all  distinct partno data in the database. So, based on the record above, the result should return two(2) rows, namely row 1 and 6 only

Comment: can you print what the above query gives output

Comment: S/N Part Number Description Recommended Price Supplier
1 17 BOLT &amp; NUT 17 BOLT &amp; NUT 600 TVH
2 2070081 6.00x9 Rim Assy Mono (Hyster H2.0-2.5FT) 25000 Bola Oguns

Comment: This is return the partno, description, minimum price but different supplier.

Comment: any idea on how to return the row that have minimum price for a particular distinct partno?, as the query above returns all columns correctly except for supplier

Answer (score 0):

The SQL MIN returns only 1 row which is the most minimum.

What you can do is fetch all records and sort them on price based on ascending order.

```
SELECT price,partno,supplier,description FROM tab_stockqty2 ORDER BY price ASC;
```

Try this instead.

In this way you will get records based on price from Low to High.
[image]

Comment: The question is for just the minimum prices not all of the records !

Comment: @M.Hamza Mehmood: The record above should only return two rows, as my final answer, not sorting.

Comment: Try this:

`SELECT price,partno,supplier,description FROM tab_stockqty2 ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT 2;`

In this way you get the 2 most minimal prices.

Comment: What happens, when the records grows into thousand, will i be limiting it by 1000? I think this will not solve the issue

Comment: No, as you said "The record above should only return two rows, as my final answer". If you always needed 2 records than `LIMIT 2` will work for you.

Comment: I only said that based on the current record in the DB. If i have 30 records with 5 distinct partno, then i will be expecting 5 rows which have minimum price as output . Do you understnd my request now?

Comment: Hmm.. May be you can try this:

`SELECT MIN(price) AS price,partno,supplier,description FROM tab_stockqty2 GROUP BY partno ORDER BY price ASC`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145196/discussion-between-dave-and-m-hamza-mehmood).